# PHP Conditionals: is_null($someVariable) vs. $someVariable === 0

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I just debugged a problem I had to the root I mention down here:

The first conditional is true;
The second conditional does not execute;

Why does the 2nd conditional not execute?

```
$someVariable = 0;

if ( $someVariable === 0 ) var_dump('worked');

if ( is_null($someVariable) ) var_dump('worked too');
```

I think I saw it working in some 'legacy' code, but am not sure about it.

Comment: Not under any version of PHP known to [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/9llOe)

Comment: One must understand that 0 !== null ;)

Answer (score 4):

From the `is_null` docs:

> Returns TRUE if var is null, FALSE otherwise.

The second conditional doesn't execute because `$someVariable` isn't null.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on @jim's answer:

While `0 == null` (equals), `0 !== null` (not *identical* to).
When using the equals operator the variables are type autocast, in which case `null` becomes `0`; But when using the `identical to` operators the actual types of the values are checked too. In which case `0` is an `int`, and `null` is `null`. Which are, obviously, not the same. ;)
`is_null()` checks the type of the variable, just like the `identical` operators does. That's why it doesn't evaluate to `true`.

The PHP manual has more information about [the operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php), [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), and how it all works. I strongly recommend reading through that section a couple of times.